# Sum based on multiple columns with pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I want to create a new column that sums up the *value* column based on groupings of multiple columns. In this example I want to get the sum per *ISIN*, *date* and *portfolio*.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ISIN": ["IS123", "IS123", "UN123", "UN123", "FA123"],
                     "date": ["16", "16", "18", "18", "22"],
                     "portfolio": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "D"],
                     "value": [400, 300, 200, 600, 500]})
```

Here is the desired output. As you can see, only the first two rows "satisfies" the condition and both rows get the sum of **700**. The others will keep their respective value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ISIN": ["IS123", "IS123", "UN123", "UN123", "FA123"],
                     "date": ["16", "16", "18", "18", "22"],
                     "portfolio": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "D"],
                     "value": [400, 300, 200, 600, 500],
                     "Sum per ISIN, date and portfolio": [700, 700, 200, 600, 500]})
```

Here is what I have tried, but I am only able to make it work with grouping on one column, for example just *ISIN*.

```
df["Sum per ISIN, date and portfolio"] = df["value"].groupby(df["ISIN", "date", "portfolio"]).transform("sum")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` on the DataFrame instead of the Series (`value`) then select the column from the grouper:

```
df["Sum per ISIN, date and portfolio"] = (
    df.groupby(["ISIN", "date", "portfolio"])["value"].transform("sum")
)
```

```
    ISIN date portfolio  value  Sum per ISIN, date and portfolio
0  IS123   16         A    400                               700
1  IS123   16         A    300                               700
2  UN123   18         B    200                               200
3  UN123   18         A    600                               600
4  FA123   22         D    500                               500
```